# Python RSA Decrypt for class using vs2013

Tags: python, visual-studio, encryption, cryptography, rsa

For my class assignment we need to decrypt a message that used RSA Encryption.  We were given code that should help us with the decryption, but its not helping.

```
def block_decode(x):
    output = ""
    i = BLOCK_SIZE+1    
    while i > 0:
        b1 = int(pow(95,i-1))
        y = int(x/b1) 
        i = i - 1
        x = x - y*b1
        output = output + chr(y+32)
    return output
```

I'm not great with python yet but it looks like it is doing something one character at a time.  What really has me stuck is the data we were given.  Can't figure out where or how to store it or if it is really decrypted data using RSA.  below are just 3 lines of 38 lines some lines have ' or " or even multiple.

```
FWfk ?0oQ!#|eO Wgny 1>a^ 80*^!(l{4! 3lL qj'b!.9#'!/s2_
!BH+V YFKq _@:X &?A8 j_p< 7\[0 la.[ a%}b E`3@ d3N? ;%FW
 KyYM!"4Tz yuok J;b^!,V4) \JkT .E[i i-y* O~$? o*1u d3N?
```

**How do I get this into a string list?**

Comment: what is `BLOCK_SIZE` value?

Comment: it was 4, I never was able to figure out the code to decode it.  the encode we were given created a big number that the code you see above would choke on.  Since I had never done this before I was unable to figure out how to decode it.  even though it said it should take me 4 hours.  I worked well over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the function `ord` which is a built-in function that

> Returns the integer ordinal of a one-character string.

So for instance, you can do:

```
my_file = open("file_containing_encrypted_message")
data = my_file.read()
```

to read in the encrypted contents.

Then, you can iterate over each character doing

```
char_val = ord(each_character)
block_decode(char_val)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.  Now onto figuring out how to fully decrypt what I was given now that it is in a list.  I was hoping just running it through their routine they gave us would be enough. but its not :(